# jQuery delete all rows except the hidden row in a table

Tags: jquery, html-table, rows

A simple solution that I am searching in jQuery to delete all the table rows except the hidden row in a table. Here, I have tried with basic level (I'm new to this pardon me.).

```
$("#example-datatable tbody tr:not(:hidden)").remove();
```

HTML Code:

```
 <table id="example-datatable" class="table draggable table-striped table-bordered table-vcenter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Account Name</th>
            <th>Meeting Date</th>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>No Of Hours</th>
            <th>Project</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Created By</th>
            <th>Created On</th>
            <th>Modified By</th>
            <th class="text-center">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Define the Template TR to Clone for rest of the Rows -->
        <tr style="display:none">
            <td>accountName</td>
            <td>meetingDate</td>
            <td>startTime</td>
            <td>no_of_hours</td>
            <td>projectName</td>
            <td>IsActive</td>
            <td>employeeDisplayName</td>
            <td>createdDate</td>
            <td>employeeDisplayName</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <!--Buttons Binded here with primarykey ID-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: As your question is currently written, it is impossible to answer.

Comment: please share your html, then we can understand what you want to do

Comment: Please suggest me someother way to achieve this.@connexo

Comment: @RohitVerma, I have added my html code.Please look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
$("#example-datatable tbody tr").not(":hidden").remove();
```